# Can I add grout to existing grout to raise the level?

Tags: floor, grout

I grouted my bathroom floor a few days ago and was running out of grout and tried to spread it out to cover. As a result there are a couple low spots. Can I regrout over top of it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It should bond well assuming 1) the grout is still clean, and 2) you clear the surface of dust and debris. However, if the depth you're filling is extremely shallow, you may be better off in the long term by grinding most of the existing grout out first. Very thin layers of cementious material tend to flake away over time.

Comment: +1. I would add that you should ensure the existing grout is damp before you float the second layer over it.